# The web type ctf problem includes node and python

Tags: php, ctf

I am playing with the web type of ctf
Questions are as follows

```
<?php
if(!isset($_FILES["file"]))
    highlight_file(__file__) && die();
$flag = file_get_contents('/flag');
$node = @`node {$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]} 2>&1`;
$python = @`python3 {$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]} 2>&1`;
if($flag === $node && $flag === $python)
    echo 'Here is your Flag: '.$flag;
else
    echo 'Fail :(';                                         ?>
```

According to program logic,
I uploaded two files I wrote using postman form-data,
They are test.js and test.py respectively,
I want to get the flag file content in the script and compare it with the $flag variable,
But I can't get the $node variable and the $python variable to be true at the same time,
I can't get the flag,
ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need a single file that parses as valid JS and valid Python at the same time.

Here's the same code twice with Python and Javascript syntax highlighting:

### Python

```py
a = 1 // 1 ; b = '''

// Put your Javascript code here.
// Python will just assign it to a string variable
console.log('Javascript running here');

/* '''

# Put your Python code here. Javascript will ignore it
# because it's inside a comment
print('Python running here')

# */
```

### Javascript

```js
a = 1 // 1 ; b = '''

// Put your Javascript code here.
// Python will just assign it to a string variable
console.log('Javascript running here');

/* '''

# Put your Python code here. Javascript will ignore it
# because it's inside a comment
print('Python running here')

# */
```

Comment: It's amazing this helped me
but I don't know why such a python program can execute a js program

Comment: It's a [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29). The Python code only runs in Python, and the JS code only runs in JS.

Comment: Probably got it, thank you very much
The grammar is a bit difficult to understand. Are there any learning resources that I can refer to? Thank you

Comment: Any basic introduction to Python and Javascript will explain the syntax of the language and how to insert comments. Creating a polygot isn't that hard.